# Java exception - Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I am developing an application with EJB, when I make a transaction on the database I get the following error:

> Grave: RAR5031:System Exception
>   javax.resource.spi.LocalTransactionException:
>   Can't call commit when autocommit=true

The following is the code:

```
public boolean update(Person vo) {
    boolean r = false;
    try 
    {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(vo);            
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        r = true;
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
    } finally {
        return r;
    }
}
```

If this code does not invoke from an EJB not get error. I only get the error when I invoke from an EJB.

Comment: If you would use declarative container managed transactions, you would not need to explicitly begin and commit transactions. All dirty tasks are handled by the container under the hood. If you were to however, be interested in using programmatic transactions for some unclear reasons, then you could use [bean managed transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions004.htm) (injecting the `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` interfaces using the `@Resource` annotation and starting and committing transactions explicitly/programmatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this annotation `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` on your session bean.
Example:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class YourSessionBean ...
```

Answer (score 1):

All EJB methods are transactional per default. The transaction handling is performed by the EJB and thus you dont need to invoke begin() and commit().

Comment: if not invoke these methods do not persitente makes changes. you have any other ideas?